# How to implement localization with dialogs exported as libraries

Tags: node.js, localization, botframework

I have packaged some of my dialogs as libraries by following the instructions from the [basics-libraries example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node/examples/basics-libraries). Before, I had all dialogs in `app.js` and I used localization following the instructions from the [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/localization/#navtitle). For example, I used

```
var chatBot = new builder.UniversalBot(chatConnector, {
  localizerSettings: { 
    botLocalePath: "./locale", 
    defaultLocale: "de"
  }
});
```

and

```
session.preferredLocale("de");
```

to use German for all the prompt labels, and stored all the German translations in `./locale/de/index.json` and `./locale/de/BotBuilder.json`.

However, the localization doesn't work with the dialogs I have packaged into libraries. Instead of the localized strings only the message IDs are displayed.

It works if I use `session.localizer.gettext(session.preferredLocale(), "message ID")` on each string. However, that is very tedious, and I am wondering if there is a way to localize all strings inside a library at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to this to work, your locale file should have the same name as your library.

```
./my_bot_library.js
./locale/en/my_bot_library.json
```

Then, to get your localized text you can either use:

`session.localizer.gettext(session.preferredLocale(), 'message ID', 'my_bot_library')`

> Please note that the the third parameter is the namespace that
>   represents the library name

or just the following which internally resolves the preferred Locale and current namespace/library name

```
session.gettext('message_id') or session.send('message_id')
```

Comment: Thanks Ezequiel! Do you maybe also know how manual localization via `session.localizer.gettext(session.preferredLocale(), "message ID")` works? At I first I thought that this also works, but now I have realized that it always checks the message IDs inside `./locale/de/index.json` instead of the JSON named after my library.